# Defining special counter

Tags: counters

Theorem counters can be set to zero automatically on changes of chapter, section, or subsecion, by the second optional argument of `\newtheorem` (e.g. `\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}[section]` produces a theorem foo with counter `foo` that zeros at every change of chapter or section). I'd like to do that without going through a theorem, and to avoid adding the zeroing to the `\chapter` etc. macros. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Would `\numberwithin{foo}{section}` -- requires the `amsmath` package -- be acceptable? That, or `\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{foo}{section} \makeatother`.

Comment: Yep, perfect. I use `amsmath`, but only know so little about it :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well your question,

```
\newcounter{foo}[chapter]
```

does what you want. If you want that the chapter number is part of the representation of `foo`, add

```
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\thechapter.\arabic{foo}}
```

If `foo` is an already defined counter by a package and you have no control over its definition, add

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

and do

```
\counterwithin{foo}{chapter}
```

if you want that the representation of `foo` starts with the chapter number or

```
\counterwithin*{foo}{chapter}
```

otherwise.

With `\newcounter{foo}[chapter]` the counter `foo` is *bound* to `chapter`, which means it's reset each time `chapter` is stepped (with `\stepcounter`). There's no record of what counter a given one is bound to. There is, of course, the list of counters bound to a given one. The list is `\cl@<counter>`, for instance `\cl@chapter` in the `book` class expands to

```
\@elt{section}\@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{table}\@elt{footnote}
```

The `\@elt` macro is used by `\stepcounter` to reset the counter `\@elt` is given as argument. We can use it in various way, for instance to examine the list. The following code will show the status of a counter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showcounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}
    {\@latex@error{No counter `#1'}{}}
    {\typeout{`#1' is a defined counter
              with bound counters:}%
     \show@bound@counters{#1}%
     \typeout{===}}%
}
\newcommand{\show@bound@counters}[1]{%
  \begingroup % redefine \@elt in a group
  \def\@elt##1{\typeout{##1}}\@nameuse{cl@#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\showcounter{foo}
\showcounter{chapter}
\newcounter{foo}[section]

\showcounter{section}
```

If we run it through LaTeX we'll get the following output in the terminal and the log file:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter `foo'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.19 \showcounter{foo}

? 
`chapter' is a defined counter with bound counters:
section
equation
figure
table
footnote
===
`section' is a defined counter with bound counters:
subsection
foo
===
```

Comment: Is there a way to know what a counter is numbered in?

Comment: Or else: does `\counterwithout` give an error if I say e.g. `\counterwithout{foo}{chapter}` and `foo` is _not_ numbered within `chapter`?

Comment: Since it seems the answer to that is "No, it doesn't", I am done here :).

Comment: @MickG No, you can see what counters are bound to `chapter`, say, but not whether `section` is bound to `chapter` (it is, of course).

Answer (score 5):

You have (at least) two options (enter the instructions in the preamble):

- `\numberwithin{foo}{section}` (requires the `amsmath` package).

  Instances of the `foo` environment will be numbered like "1.1", "1.2", etc.
- `\makeatletter \@addtoreset{foo}{section} \makeatother`

  Instances of the `foo` environment will be numbered like "1", "2", etc. within each section, unless you do something like `\renewcommand\thefoo{\thesection.\arabic{foo}}`.

Comment: Suppose I have a counter numbered within `section` and want it to change and become numbered within `chapter`. Can I do that?

Comment: @MickG - Not sure what a use case for such a change might be. I suspect your readers will be *very confused* by mid-document changes in the numbering system of a counter. I see that egreg has provided two additional methods in his answer. The second method -- using `\counterwithout{foo}{section}` followed by `\counterwithin{foo}{chapter}` -- may meet your needs in this regard.

Comment: @MickG - It would be helpful if you stated your main objectives *up front* in the posting itself, rather than later on in comments to answers. Had I known that you were interested in changing the counter structure mid-document, I would have mentioned immediately the `chngcntr` package and its `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` macros, and I would have skipped the `\numberwithin` and `\@addtoreset` stuff.

Comment: Sorry @mico, I probably didn't think about this question long enough before posting it :). Besides, I couldn't have expected a possible way of doing what I asked in the post would not allow changing the `within`, so I'd have had to notice it with a small document and then post a comment or edit the question, which is what I did, save for the "Yep, perfect." comment. Sorry again.